# Deploying a JSP Website

Tags: linux, jsp, tomcat, web-hosting

I am trying to deploy a jsp website that I worked on. I implemented it on my windows machine and in the PATH variable I had the path to some bin directory, I am wondering where should I place this path or directory on the server I am deploying to.

The server is based on linux so I am not sure if that would make a difference.

I upload a single WAR file

I tried to place it in the lib directory but it didn't work.

Thank you

Comment: What type of web container are you using: Tomcat, Jetty, other?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Tomcat installed on your Linux server then you can just place your WAR file inside the `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` directory as described in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup).

If you do not have Tomcat installed you can follow the Tomcat documentation [setup guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) or this [blog post](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_tomcat_7_on_centos). You can also use a package manager such as [YUM](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/apache-tomcat-installation-on-linux.php) or [APT](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-install-tomcat-in-ubuntu/) depending on the server Linux distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I meant where to place the bin directory that was refenced through my PATH variable. I was able to upload and try some WAR files.
The problem is where to place the directory I used to reference by the PATH environment variable

Comment: Linux also has a [PATH](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/11.html) environment variable so you can add this _bin_ directory to it.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to the machine as I am using an online hosting service, so I wanted to check if I can just place this folder some where on the server or do any adjustments.
Thank you

Comment: why do you need this bin directory in your path? try adding more information your question